# How to get nested objects using ICriteria Projections

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, nhibernate-projections

I have data model like this:

```
class Hand {
    public int id;
    ...
}
class Person {
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public IList<Hand> hands;
    ...
}
```

To get data from database, I do this:

```
ICriteria criteria = databaseSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person));

ProjectionList projections = Projections.ProjectionList();

projections
    .Add(Projections.Property("id").As("id"))
    .Add(Projections.Property("name").As("name"))
    .Add(Projections.Property("hands").As("hands"));

projections.Add(Projections.GroupProperty("id"));
projections.Add(Projections.Count("id"), "count");

criteria.SetProjection(projections);

criteria.SetResultTransformer(
    NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(PersonDTO)));
```

But NHibernate does not load nested objects in hands property. It just gives null.
Can anyone help me how to get nested objects filled as well (for more than one level depth). Using projections instead of query would be better for me.
Note: It would not be issue in the mapping, because when I loaded data without any projection, it worked well.

Comment: try to think of a sql which does group by id and returns all hands in one go. IMO it's not possible like that. load the objects complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a possible solution

```
var query = databaseSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person))
    .JoinAlias("hands", "hand")
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("Id"))
        .Add(Projections.Property("Name"))
        .Add(Projections.Property("hand.Id"))
        .Add(Projections.Property("hand.Foo")))
    .List<object[]>()
    .GroupBy(arr => (int)arr[0])
    .Select(g => new PersonDTO
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Name = g.First().Name,
        Hands = g.Select(arr => new Hand { Id = arr[2], Foo = arr[3] }).ToList(),
    });

var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: But that seems to me that the group by is done after fetching data from DB - so it's not done by database but the application. Am I right?

Comment: yes because you can only select aggregates and grouped columns when grouping. So you loose the hand data when grouping. You need to select all data and transform them client side. Other than that you could only fetch them in two steps: 1 to fetch the grouped Persons and one to get the hands

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. But for me, it would be better to fetch grouped persons first and then fill it's nested objects... Thanks very much for your help

Comment: why do you group by id? this does basicly nothing since the id should be unique. If you group over another property which nestet objects do you want to fill in since one group contains multiple parent objects?

Comment: That's because my query gives me more instances of the same object, so I need to group them by ID (like performing distinct but with count given) and moreover it became an advantage that I will load nested objects later because now I'm going to filter persons by more than one query